# How to power 6 number of MG995 servos connected in 16 channel servo controller

Tags: batteries, servo

I am building a robotic arm having 6 number of MG995 servos. Each servos requires 4.8 to 6 v. I am controlling them using 12 bit 16 channel servo controller. How can I power the servo controller/ which battery suits for it?

[Robotic Arm Module](https://www.thingbits.net/products/6-dof-robotic-arm-kit-with-servo-motors-unassembled)

Comment: Specs first before choosing parts

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the current potentially drawn by your servos and the voltage you want to run them at.

Servo details for the NG995 vary somewhat but [this](http://learn.makeblock.com/en/mg995-standard-servo/) may give you an idea.
While that data shows only 4.8v supply, many others show a range of 4.8-7.2V for the servo, so selecting 5V would seem reasonable for both the controller and the servos.

The current is more challenging.
Running current may be around 6*350mA --> 2.1A 
However you are likely to have to cope with stall currents and this could result in a peak current of 6*1.5A --> 9A under worst case conditions.

This would lead you to providing a 5V 10A power supply (50W) as a reasonable recommendation.

You could use a single LiPo (3.6-4.2V) rated at 8-10000mA and a Boost DC-DC convertor to get to 5V. There are endless variants on Ebay.

However I'd suggest you may be better going to a 2 cell LiPo (2S, nominally 7.7V)) of about 5000mA rating and use a Buck DC-DC convertor.
Again there are lots of Buck convertors on Ebay that would suit.

I'd further suggest you should power each servo from it's own Buck convertor. There are switching replacements of the LM7805 that would ideally suit; [here](https://news.ezsbc.com/coming-soon-switch-mode-regulator-drop-in-replacement-for-lm7805/) is an example.
The reason for suggesting you use multiple DC-DC convertors is that the individual convertor can limit the stall current to each servo, so when it stalls the voltage driving it drops. The 7805 replacements typically are rated at about 1A which in this case is less than the stall current for your servo.
Using 2S LiPo also means the wiring in your robot arm has to support much less current so can be thinner and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a 5V power supply. If you're okay with it being powered off mains (probably, looks like it's a fixed robot arm), you can get a cheap 5V power supply that can plug into mains. Check your local electronics store, online store.

You can get an "industrial" one that looks like this (when you work with this, be careful with handling live mains wire; unplug everything before you handle the screw terminals)

[image: "industrial" power supply]

Or you could even salvage a USB phone charger. You could get a spare USB cable and cut off the end to expose the red and black wire which carries the 5V power.

If you're looking for a battery powered option, you could get a AA battery holder that holds 4 AA batteries (might be higher than 6V, but it's probably gonna be alright), or get a 2S LiPo battery (2S means there are 2x 3.7V cells in series), and a step down buck converter module from the usual places (adafruit, amazon, ebay, aliexpress). Be sure to pick up a lipo balance charger, because you can't charge them without one. Be extra careful handling LiPo batteries. If you are new to LiPo, I suggest you either do your research or go for the AA battery option.

Answer (score -1):

I bought a 6v battery. it solved the issue.